# How to redirect out going traffic to an IP address to another host name?

Tags: hosts

How can I redirect an IP say 203.130.48.8-bj-cnc or 203.130.48.8 to Google.com in host file (or other places)?

It looks like host file doesn't redirect an ip address (only the domain names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 203.130.48.8-bj-cnc (subtype ip address) and 203.130.48.8 (traditional ip address) are "ip address" instead of "alias," adding them in host file will not do anything. The system will bypass the rules you set up.

The only way to redirect ip request is to use third party software like little snitch. They are usually not free. This is because Unix based system will go through ip address directly when requesting instead of wasting time on capture them to enhance performance. Third party software basically reduce the overall efficiency by query ip requests.

Another way to do it is to set up rules in your gateway, that's only if your gateway can do it and if you have a gateway to begin with.

I know host file is probably the most convenient way to deal with this, but it simply won't work. Move on, stop wasting time on it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify whether you want to block incoming traffic from that host name or outgoing or both. You also don't mention what version of Mac OS X you are running and whether or not you are trying to block that host with a specific application like Little Snitch or similar. Some logs would be helpful as well. Consult [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you formulate better questions for the community to be able to answer.

203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC is a valid hostname according to [IETF standard RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952).

> A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
> to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
> sign (-), and period (.).

To block outgoing traffic to it, use the hostname in your `/etc/hosts` file like so:

```
127.0.0.1    203.130.48.8-bj-cnc
```

Then do:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

to load the new rules.

If you want to be able to block outgoing traffic to the actual ip address of the machine you'll need to use Mac's builtin packet filter (originally from [OpenBSD's excellent PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/). A pf.conf rule would look like this:

```
block out log quick on $ext_if proto { tcp, udp, icmp } to 203.130.48.8
```

Blocking incoming traffic from that ip is generally handled just fine by using Mac OS X's default application firewall in ` -> System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall`. Alternatively you can set the policy via the commandline like so:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setblockall on
```

for thoroughness, you may also want to block all icmp requests:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setstealthmod on
```

and finally enable it thus:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate on
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like 203.130.48.8-bj-cnc is actually an IP address rather than a host name, this is why "127.0.0.1   203.130.48.8-bj-cnc" doesn't work.

Comment: hostnames are allowed to have numbers in them. So 203.130.48.8-bj-cnc is a valid hostname even though it contains an ip address in it. You need to make sure that you flush the dns cache of your machine after inputting the rule. Tested and working on Mac OS X Mavericks. 

`sudo vi /etc/hosts | grep 203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC`
# test block 203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC
127.0.0.1       203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC

`ping 203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC`
PING 203.130.48.8-bj-cnc (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms

Comment: Have you tested if it works when you redirect this "host name" to a new ip address? If so can you upload your host file? Thanks.

Comment: See my comment above. The test is to ping the hostname and the response indicates 127.0.0.1 which is the localhost (your machine).

    # test block 203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC in /etc/hosts 
    127.0.0.1       203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC

Comment: I am pretty sure it doesn't work. Have you tried hosting a local web page and visit the 'host name' in your browser? Ping only gives you the idea how fast the server responses.

Comment: Ping is telling you what it thinks the hostname's ip address resolves to. If you set up the /etc/hosts file correctly, flush the cache, and then ping the hostname in terminal, you should be getting 127.0.0.1 as the resonse.

Comment: Have you tried hosting a local web page and visit the 'host name' in your browser?

Comment: Yes. I just fired up an instance of MAMP. Setup a test page (testhostblock.php) in my document root, and browsed to http://203.130.48.8-BJ-CNC/testhostblock.php and received the expected response in my browser (in this case the script just pulls the ip address of the server which was as expected 127.0.0.1).